# Check if Django model field choices exists

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm attempting to check if a value exists in the choices tuple set for a model field.

For example lets say I have a Model like this:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
 VOTE_TYPE = (
  (1, "Up"),
  (-1, "Down"),
 )

 value = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=1, choices=VOTE_TYPES)
```

Now lets say in a view I have a variable `new_value = 'Up'` that I would like to use as the value field in a new Vote.  How can I first check to see if the value of that variable exists in the VOTE_TYPE tuple?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Are you sure you want to set value to "Up"? that is a display value, you might be interested in setting value to -1 or 1
2. You can easily check if a choice is in list by converting choice list to dict e.g.

   `my_choice in dict(VOTE_TYPE)`
3. If possible you can use choiceField or TypedChoiceField , they will validate that the given value exists in the list of choices.

Comment: 1. "Up" is the readable value of 1 which is what would be entered into the db.
2. This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Worked Perfectly
3. I'll also look into this
4. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

All new projects probably use `TextChoices` or `IntegerChoices`.
As it inherits from a builtin `enum.Enum`, you can now check it in a way your intuition tells you.

```
from django.db.models import TextChoices


class ExampleChoices(TextChoices):
    example_a = "a"
    example_b = "b", "display_b"
```

```
>>> "a" in ExampleChoices
True
>>> "b" in ExampleChoices
True
>>> "display_b" in ExampleChoices
False
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, `models.SmallIntegerField` cannot have a `max_length` option. That are used only in `CharField` and it's derivatives. Secondly, according to the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices), the `choices` option is mainly used by Django for the Admin site. That said, one option you have is to import the VOTE_TYPE tuple from you `models.py` file into your `views.py` file and then checking the value - something like:

```
models.py
...
VOTE_TYPE = ( (1, "Up"), (-1, "Down"), )

views.py
...
from app.models import VOTE_TYPE
for k,v in VOTE_TYPE:
    if v == new_value:
        return True
```

Also, if I remember right, you can create a `ModelForm` from your model and then pass in values to said form which should validate the data against the VOTE_TYPE tuple.

Comment: This way also worked, although in a few more lines.  Thanks for the tip about the max_lengt hin a SmallIntegerField.